# Telerik Test Studio Mobile Web Automation problems

Tags: automated-tests, telerik-test-studio

Recently I've been exploring the tool from Telerik called Test Studio. And after 3 weeks of using it I still have some questions that I couldn't find the answers for. Did anyone have an experience with this tool? The guys from Telerik are not answering, so I decided to post my questions here.

Here they are:
- Is it possible to add a manual step for mobile web test? It's easy to do for the normal web, but couldn't find this functionality for mobile web.
- Is it possible to simulate the real text typing for mobile web test? Again, I was able to do it for the normal web, but can't find the same function for mobile.

Will appreciate any help! Thank you in advance :)